# Double colored border for UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I would like to setup an image with 2 borders around it. Is it possible to duplicate the `borderWidth` property on the same image view somehow? Like this:

```
   // inner circle/border
   self.avatar.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
   // outer circle/border
   self.avatar.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;

  UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(24.0 / 255.0) green:(169.0 / 255.0) blue:(250.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
  UIColor *myColor2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:(24.0 / 255.0) green:(169.0 / 255.0) blue:(20.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
   self.avatar.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor;
   self.avatar.layer.borderColor = myColor2.CGColor;
```

Unfortunately this code doesn't work, but if there is any solution that's easy like this I would be very happy with it. Actually my only idea is to duplicate the `UIImageView`, put it under the "real" image and set border for it. This way would work, but I need a cleaner solution.

Comment: Just put UIImageView inside another UIView and setup borders for both of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can add your `UIImageView` inside a `UIView` and set the layer of that `UIView`.

You can do it like:

```
self.avatar.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
UIColor *myColor   = [UIColor colorWithRed:(24.0 / 255.0) green:(169.0 / 255.0) blue:(250.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
UIColor *myColor2  = [UIColor colorWithRed:(24.0 / 255.0) green:(169.0 / 255.0) blue:(20.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
CGPoint point      = self.avatar.frame.origin;
CGFloat width      = self.avatar.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height     = self.avatar.frame.size.height;
UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, width+4, height+4)];

holderView.layer.borderWidth  = 2.0;
self.avatar.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor;
holderView.layer.borderColor  = myColor2.CGColor;
[self.avatar setFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, width, height)];
[holderView addSubview:self.avatar];
[self.view addSubview:holderView];
```

Or you can add a new `CALayer` as a sublayer of your existing layer to do this.

Comment: It seems it's working, but the view is a little bit shifted to the right side. Is it possible to solve it somehow?

Comment: @bushiko: Can you put a screenshot ?

Comment: you can use [RSUIImageViewMultiborder](https://github.com/ratulSharker/RSUIImageViewMultiborder)